# PHP send email to multiple recipients (headers not sending)

Tags: php, forms, email-headers

I have an index.html and a contacto.php.

contacto.php is supposedly meant to send the user's info to multiple recipients but it's not sending.

This is my index.html (ignore the javascript)

```
<form action="contacto.php" method="POST">

        <fieldset style="margin: 0px 0 0 0"; >
<br/><br/>  <br/><br/>  <br/><br/>  <br/><br/>


<input maxlength="255" name="Form testing" size="20" type="hidden" value="Form-name-here" /><br>    

 <input value="Nome" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Nome') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Nome';}" maxlength="255" name="name" size="20" type="text" /><br>

<input value="Telemóvel" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Telemóvel') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Telemóvel';}" id="phone" maxlength="40" name="phone" size="20" type="text" /><br>

<input onfocus="if (this.value == 'Email') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Email';}" value="Email" id="email" maxlength="80" name="email" size="20" type="text" /><br>

<input onfocus="if (this.value == 'Localidade') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Localidade';}" value="Localidade" maxlength="255" name="location" size="20" type="text" /><br>
```

.

And this is my contacto.php:

```
<?php
 // Get Data
 $name = strip_tags($_POST['name']);
 $email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
 $phone = strip_tags($_POST['phone']);
 $location = strip_tags($_POST['location']);

 $headers .="De: Form thingy <examplealpha@someemail.com>";
 $headers .="CC: Mail1 <example1@someemail.com>";
 $headers .=", Mail2 <example2@someemail.com>";

 header("Location: thankyou.html");  //Redirect to Thank You HTML page after email is sent


 // Send message
 mail( "example1@someemail.com", "Formulário Facebook Av. Grátis",
 "Name: $name\nEmail: $email\nPhone: $phone\nLocation: $location\n",
  $headers );
 ?>
```

Comment: Change `$headers .="De: Form thingy <examplealpha@someemail.com>";` to `$headers ="From: Form thingy <examplealpha@someemail.com>";` `"De:` is not standard, use `"From:....`.

Comment: @Fred holy moly, you're right. Will that work if I change it now? I'll try and report back.

Comment: Give it a try and see. Have you tested the other person's answer? I posted mine below. Theoretically, it should.

Comment: And follow what Adidi said about redirection "after" `mail(....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Change:**

```
$headers .="De: Form thingy <examplealpha@someemail.com>";
```

**To:**

```
$headers ="From: Form thingy <examplealpha@someemail.com>";
```

"De: is not standard as per PHP manual, use "From:....

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

http://php.net/manual/fr/function.mail.php

**Full code:**

```
<?php
// Get Data
$name = strip_tags($_POST['name']);
$email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
$phone = strip_tags($_POST['phone']);
$location = strip_tags($_POST['location']);

$headers ="From: Form thingy <examplealpha@someemail.com>";
$headers .="CC: Mail1 <example1@someemail.com>";
$headers .=", Mail2 <example2@someemail.com>";

// Send message
mail( "example1@someemail.com", "Formulário Facebook Av. Grátis",
 "Name: $name\nEmail: $email\nPhone: $phone\nLocation: $location\n",
  $headers );

header("Location: thankyou.html");  //Redirect to Thank You HTML page after email is sent
?>
```

Comment: As "Adidi" stated `put the header location redirect after the send not before`. Send being `mail(....`

Comment: Holy spokes, just worked like that. Now I just need to make the fields required. Answer checked.

Comment: @Veronica Glad to hear it worked for you. Work with a `copy` of it, so if something goes nuts, you'll still have an original `working` copy. Cheers ;-)

Comment: Thank you Fred. Thank you Adidi as well.

Answer (score 1):

put the header location redirect after the send not before

```
// Send message
mail( "example1@someemail.com", "Formulário Facebook Av. Grátis",
 "Name: $name\nEmail: $email\nPhone: $phone\nLocation: $location\n",
 $headers );

 header("Location: thankyou.html");  //Redirect to Thank You HTML page after email is sent
```

Comment: edited that bit just now, went back and filled in the form again but it didn't send any email. I may be missing some bit of code?

Comment: Are you using your local environment ? or some server ? did your have php logs to some place ?

Comment: I'm using my server. Should I use php logs? I don't know how to use them. Did it help if I linked here the URL to the form?

Comment: the "mail" function return true/false - try to print that: $result = mail("exa.... - what is the result ?

Comment: should I add  mail("myemail@email.com", $subject, $text); to the php file to know that?

Comment: just get the return value from the function and print it (echo it or something)

Comment: sorry I don't know how to do that, I'm a php newbie. In either case thanks a lot for your help. This form is not sending any emails, I should learn php properly instead of hacking snippets of pho code together.

Comment: This didn't work but I checked your answer in either case, thanks.